# copy files and folders to another path using batch

Tags: python, windows, vbscript, batch-file

I have a directory c:/go , inside go there is tons of folders, subfolders and files.

I need to find inside go, files that start with net*.inf and oem*.inf , and copy the folder, subfolders and all files where they are to another palce at c:/

It must be something automatic using windows... like batch script, c++, python...vbs pleasee!! thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

From the command line, one way is to combine [xcopy](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) with a [for loop](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/for.php):

```
for /D %i in (net oem) do xcopy /s c:\go\%i*.inf c:\go2\
```

In a batch file just replace `%i` with `%%i`.

Comment: thankkkyou veru muchh!! I was breaking my head and it end up beeing so easy code ... although I got error tryng to copy from c:go to c:go/go2. ... I guess its because its inside the source folder... any ideas?

Comment: also The code copy the inf and his respective folder but how to download the others files inside the
same
folder?

Comment: @masaki: you could do it in two steps: copy from c:\go\ to c:\go2\ as above, then `move` c:\go2\ to be under c:\go\.  On your second comment, I'm not sure what you mean by "others files inside the same folder".  Which other files?

Comment: I mean inside /go there is alot of other files... as well the .inf. ... i need all other files including the inf ... but I just want all files from the folders that have .inf files that contain the word nrt or oem.... :)

Comment: so i guess I must be something like xcopy /s \go\*.*.but only for foldera where the inf have the "net"...

Answer (score 2):

The xcopy technique in @ars' answer is obviously simpler for your situation if it is appropriate for you.  However, below is a Python implementation.  It will make sure the target directory is there and create it if it isn't:

```
#!python
import os
import re
import shutil

def parse_dir(src_top, dest_top):
    re1 = re.compile("net.*\.inf")
    re2 = re.compile("oem.*\.inf")
    for dir_path, dir_names, file_names in os.walk(src_top):
        for file_name in file_names:
            if re.match(re1, file_name) or re.match(re2, file_name):
                target_dir = dir_path.replace(src_top, dest_top, 1)
                if not os.path.exists(target_dir):
                    os.mkdir(target_dir)
                src_file = os.path.join(dir_path, file_name)
                dest_file = os.path.join(target_dir, file_name)
                shutil.copyfile(src_file, dest_file)

src_top = "\\go"
dest_top = "\\dest"

parse_dir(src_top, dest_top)
```

Improvements are probably possible, but this should get you started if you want to go this way.

Comment: Conditional directory creation can be trivially retrofitted to the batch with a single line, though.

Comment: @Joey: Yes, that was part of my reference to ars' answer.  I just offered this as an alternative ... also it should work on *nix platforms (with a minor change of the path separator to /, which will work on Windows, but I used the \ so that the code looks more "Windows-like").

Comment: thank you as well I really apreciate ... Also
will try wirh putjon code